# how to implement fabric multiple settings?

Tags: python, fabric

I need to apply multiple `fabric` setting together, is there a convenient way?

I can achieve this by the following code:

```
with settings(warn_only=True), hide('stdout'), cd('/tmp/'):
    #do something
```

It works on an environment with `python` 2.7.6, but fails on another enviroment with `python` 2.6.6.

I don't want to change the code like this:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    with hide('stdout'):
        with cd('/tmp/'):
            #do something
```

It looks so complex and brings too many indents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's built-in [`contextlib.nested`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nested) method:

```
from contextlib import nested

with nested(settings(warn_only=True), hide('stdout'), cd('/tmp/')):
    # do something really cool
```